# How do I only get one word from a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm writing an English to Spanish dictionary in python. I have the user input what they want translated and the my program reads a file I created and print the Spanish equivalent of the word. Currently it just print the whole dictionary. This is probably easy but I am new to this and can't seem to figure it out. Thanks

```
`# coding: utf-8
s=(input("please enter a word to be translated: "))
file=open("dictionary.txt")
engtospa={}
for s in file:
    aList=s.split()
    b=aList[0:]
    engtospa[s]=aList[1:0]
print(engtospa)

`
```

Comment: `engtospa['word']`?

Comment: Indexing a dictionary is a very basic concept, and most likely off-topic for Stack Overflow. I suggest taking a look at the [documentation on dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Comment: Also, you might consider using `json` instead of a plain text-file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the key which you want to translate.

```
# coding: utf-8
s=(input("please enter a word to be translated: "))
file=open("dictionary.txt")
engtospa={}
for s in file:
    aList=s.split()
    b=aList[0:]
    engtospa[s]=aList[1:0]
print(engtospa) # <-- your code 
print(engtospa[s]) # <-- expected
```